# how to write complex queries with supabase sdk?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase

i have this postgresql query, not sure i can translate it to a supabase query by using the standard supabase sdk.
please ignore the fact that some parts of it are in hebrew,
but basically the goal of this query is to retrieve a new table with some predefined options to filter on the FE, and the count of each filter

when i run it via `sql editor` in supabase dashboard i get something like this:

| category | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| difficulty | mental | 25 |
| difficulty | financial | 153 |
| diagnosis | psychodidactic | 12 |
| diagnosis | didactic | 87 |

```
WITH 
  flat_filters AS (
    SELECT
      students.class AS class,
      students.gender AS gender,
      students.diagnosis AS diagnosis,
      students.health AS health,
      difficulties.type AS difficulty_type,
      COUNT(DISTINCT(students.id)) AS cnt
    FROM
      students
    LEFT JOIN
      difficulties ON students.id = difficulties.student_id
    GROUP BY
      class, gender, diagnosis, health, difficulties.type
  ),
  filters_count AS (
    SELECT
      'כיתה' AS category,
      class::varchar AS name,
      SUM(cnt) AS value
    FROM
      flat_filters
    GROUP BY
      name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'מין' AS category,
      gender::varchar AS name,
      SUM(cnt) AS value
    FROM
      flat_filters
    GROUP BY
      name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'אבחון' AS category,
      diagnosis::varchar AS name,
      SUM(cnt) AS value
    FROM
      flat_filters
    GROUP BY
      name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'קושי' AS category,
      difficulty_type::varchar AS name,
      SUM(cnt) AS value
    FROM
      flat_filters
    GROUP BY
      name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'תכנית' AS category,
      'סודקות' AS name,
      COUNT(*) AS value
    FROM
      programs
    WHERE
      sodkot = true
    GROUP BY
      sodkot
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'תכנית' AS category,
      'ממצים' AS name,
      COUNT(*) AS value
    FROM
      programs
    WHERE
      mamazim = true
    GROUP BY
      mamazim
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'תכנית' AS category,
      'ממריאים' AS name,
      COUNT(*) AS value
    FROM
      programs
    WHERE
      mamriim = true
    GROUP BY
      mamriim
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'תכנית' AS category,
      'עמיתים' AS name,
      COUNT(*) AS value
    FROM
      programs
    WHERE
      amitim = true
    GROUP BY
      amitim
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  filters_count
WHERE
  name != ''
ORDER BY
  category, name ASC
```

as said earlier, tried running the query via dashboard. attached a table for example

Answer (score 1):

ok so it turns out `supabase` is familiar with `views` as well.
i just defined a new view with
`CREATE VIEW filters AS {{query from above}}`

and in the client i simply called `supabase.from('filters').select('*');`